# Cannot edit newly created tag wiki

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, suggested-edits

Error: Edit queue full.
(This may be a little presumptuous, but I am probably the only person editing the wiki for I created the tag around 15 mins ago)

[image: Error]

How was I allowed to create one but am not allowed to edit my own tag's wiki?

Comment: The edit queue is not per question/wiki, but a single queue for all suggested edits. As long as 500 edits are active, you have to wait until someone reviews them.

Comment: @BDL, ok Thanks a lot! but now isn't that a little weird? I mean, shouldn't it be per tag?

Comment: Why would it? If that would be the case, finding reviewers for low volume tags would be almost impossible.

Comment: What I do not understand is, why do I need a special reviewer to edit my own tag's wiki?

Comment: Because your reputation is too low to edit tag wikis without review. Only trusted users (20k reputation) can edit tag wikis without review.

Comment: *"to edit my own tag's wiki"* - Because it's not _your_ tag. You simply created it, the tags are the community's.

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him don't get too optimistic about that - the number of reviewers with 5K+ reputation (required to even see tag wiki suggested edits) is quite low in the first place, and there are even fewer of those who actually review. Be prepared to have to wait up to 1.5 months. An additional issue with tag wiki edits is that they are *randomly* inserted between normal edit suggestions, so there is no guarantee reviewers will see it soon.

Comment: "*I mean, shouldn't it be per tag?*" There is a single edit that can be pending on a post, tag wiki, or tag excerpt. Having multiple pending edits for the same source is what doesn't make sense. What if both are completely different? What if both are exactly the same? What if there is some same some different parts? How would any of this be reconciled?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your new tag is a duplicate of the [counting-sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counting-sort) tag.  Your questions have already been retagged by other users so it will cease to exist automatically now that it has no questions.

Unfortunately the existing tag [counting-sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/counting-sort) tag wiki is plagiarised from Wikipedia so it does need to be edited so that it isn't.

Comment: Tag wiki aside, the excerpt is actually not plagiarised from wikipedia. It's plagiarised from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/, which I find infinitely more ironic in context for some weird reason. I've retroactively rejected both edits